# Variable changes after I change the element of array I defined it with?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I cannot comprehend what is happening in this picture. I define a variable temp and it changes on it's own after I change the array I defined it with. It's not how I thought it works at all.

I'm using Python 3.6.1 if it matters.

[image: Situation]

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image.

Answer (score 1):

A numpy array is not like Python lists. The array is a single object, and when you index it you get slices that refer to parts of the array. The rows are not independent objects, they're just views into the array.

So the value of `temp` is a reference to the first row of the array. Assigning to `matrika[0]` modifies the array. It's analogous to doing a slice assignment with regular lists, e.g.

```
matrika = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [5, 5, 5], [53, 1, 2]]
temp = matrika[0]
matrika[0][:] = matrika[1]
print(temp)
```

Comment: fundamentally, the problem is that `matrika[0]` creates a *new array object* but doesn't copy the underlying buffer from `matrika`, and instead, shares that buffer, creating two views over the same data

Comment: That's what I tried to express in my first paragraph.

Comment: I know, I upvoted, just sort of elaborating in a comment :) perhaps you can add `temp.flags` and show the output where you can see `OWNDATA : False`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. My question is how should I proceed if I wanted temp to keep the original matrika[0], not just point at it's current value?

Comment: Use `np.copy()` to make a copy of the array.